# Как работать с var в C#?

Tags: c#, vkontakte-api

Пишу парсер для ВК, так как я ооочень зеленый программист, возникла проблема.
получаю со стены в джейсоне инфу.

```
var wall = api.Wall.Get(-id, out totalCount, count);
```

и затем могу добавить в листбокс, таким способом.

```
foreach (var one in wallpost)
{
    listBox1.Items.Add(one.Text);
}
```

Вопрос. Как мне записать `one.Text` в массив? Спасибо!

Comment: var - это просто автоматическое выявление типа. Посмотрите, что возвращает метод, оттуда узнаете конкретный тип.

Comment: Ну я так понял он возвращает Json

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**var** используется для определения типа во время компиляции, т.е. её значение определяется результатом выражения.

Она создана, для облегчения инициализации переменных, когда наименование типа длинное, не имеет значение или же вообще не помнишь, какой тип там возвращает та или иная функция.

VisualStudio понимает эту переменную еще до компиляции. Т.к. `Wall.Get` возвращает `ReadOnlyCollection<Post>`, то можно облегчить себе задачу и не вводить такую кучу букв, а воспользоваться ключевым словом **var**. Тогда `wall[0].Text` будет все равно доступно и intellisense выведет его в подсказке.

Answer (score 5):

В большинстве случаев `var` работает так: определается тип значения присваемового выражения и подставляется вместо `var`.

О меньшинстве случаев можно не задумываться. Но если интересно, то `var` является не ключевым словом, а *контекстным* ключевым словом. Соответственно его можно использовать, например, в качестве имени переменной или класса. Если найдётся класс с именем `var`, то это слово уже нельзя будет использовать для выведения типа.

Сейчас рассматривается вопрос о добавлении `val`, которое будет означать неизменяемую переменную с выводом типа как и у `var`.

Answer (score 1):

Нашел решение.

```
 ReadOnlyCollection<Post> wall = api.Wall.Get(-id, out totalCount, count);
 MessageBox.Show("Text: " + wall[0].Text);
```